Closure of a set with Sorgenfrey topology
In a certain exercise I have been asked to find the closure of the set $A = (-\infty,-\sqrt{2}) \cup [\sqrt{2},3)$ with the Sorgenfrey topology (the one whose basis is $\{[a,b) : a < b, a,b \in \mathbb{R} \}$. My guess is that the clsure is $(-\infty,-\sqrt2)\cup [\sqrt2,3)$.

The only "problematic" points would be $-\sqrt{2},3$. I hold that they are not in the closure because for each there is at least a neighbourhood that contains them, but whose intersection with the set $A$ is empty. These are $[-\sqrt2,1)$, for example, and $[3,4)$. The intersection of these with each point is clearly $\{-\sqrt2\},\{3 \}$, but their intersection with $A$ is empty, so the closure would be the one I said before (this means that the set is closed). Btw, the derived set would be also the same as this one. Am I right?

You're right. You could also see that the complement is the union of two open sets, which is perhaps easier.

A set is closed if its complement is open. This set's complement is $[-\sqrt2,3)\cup[3,+\infty)$ is clearly a union of basis elements.

Being proved in the comments that $A$ is closed, a property of the derived set is that $A'\subseteq A$. To see the other inclusion, it suffices to check that there is no isolated points in $A$, which is true because no open set $[a,b)$ intersecting with $A$ gives a singleton.
